# Discord JS/MongoDB SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I ran into a problem trying to add an else if() function (I think that's what it is called) but as soon as I do, I run into annoying errors!

Here's the original code,

```
if(command === 'clue1') {
            client.commands.get('clue1').execute(message, client); 
            await configDB.updateOne({
                Clue_1: "True"
            })

            const collection = db.collection('clues')

            if(collection.find({ _id: ("ID HERE") }, {Clue1_Status: "True"}, (err, data) => {
                if (err) console.error(err)
                  return !data;
                })
              )
              return
            
              
            collection.find({ _id: ("ID HERE") }, {Clue1_Status: "False"}, async (err, data) => {
                if (err) console.error(err)
                if (data) {
                    const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()

                    .setTitle(`:partying_face: ${message.author.tag}` + " Just solved `Clue 1` :partying_face:")
                    .setColor(0xFFFF00)
                    client.channels.fetch("Channel ID")
                    .then(message => 
                        message.send(embed1)
                    )
                    await configDB1.updateOne({
                    Clue1_Status : "True"
                    })
                }
            })
    }
```

Here's the code I want to change it to:

```
if(command === 'clue1') {
            client.commands.get('clue1').execute(message, client); 
            await configDB.updateOne({
                Clue_1: "True"
            })

            const collection = db.collection('clues')

            if(collection.find({ _id: ("ID HERE") }, {Clue1_Status: "True"}, (err, data) => {
                if (err) console.error(err)
                  return !data;
                })
              )
              return
            
              
            collection.find({ _id: ("ID HERE") }, {Clue1_Status: "False"}, async (err, data) => {
                if (err) console.error(err)
                if (data) {
                    const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()

                    .setTitle(`:partying_face: ${message.author.tag}` + " Just solved `Clue 1` :partying_face:")
                    .setColor(0xFFFF00)
                    client.channels.fetch("Channel ID")
                    .then(message => 
                        message.send(embed1)
                    )
                    await configDB1.updateOne({
                    Clue1_Status : "True"
                    })
                }
            })
            )}
```

But I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'`

(I removed some of the code (ID's etc) for privacy reasons)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just made a typo in the last line. Try changing `)}` to `}`

Comment: Hmm, I still get ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'```

Comment: Line 130 - 
```Clue1_Status : "True"
                    })
                }
            })
       -->     } ```

Ugh sry bout formatting

Comment: Ok, so it does have something to do with the last line.

Comment: When I paste your code into my code to check for linting errors, I get a `Unexpected token )}` pointing to the parentheses rather than the bracket, could any of the private code you didn't include have something to do with it?

Comment: Actually... I am finding that ```collection.find({ ... Clue1_Status: "False"}...```
Is seeming to be the problem, whether that be with trying to use the if() function or with the database itself...

Comment: Oh I think I found the problem I was trying to solve using the if() function - When the bot finds that there is already a value called "True", instead of ending using ```return```, it creates a new array